# Data not displaying with MVC model when running simulator in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I've been working on putting together a simple program that will display user information in an MVC model.  The application works perfectly when all the data is on the View Controller, however, when attempting to move the data to a Profile model, the application will successfully build, however, no information will show up.  Here is the code that I'm working with right now.

The Profile View Controller header:

```
DefaultProfileViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Profile.h"

@interface DefaultProfileViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fullNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Profile *profile;

@end
```

The Profile View Controller Implementation

```
#import "DefaultProfileViewController.h"

@class Profile;

@interface DefaultProfileViewController ()

@end

@implementation DefaultProfileViewController

@synthesize profile = _profile;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _fullNameLabel.text = _profile.fullName;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The Profile model header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Profile : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fullName;

- (void)loadProfile:(NSString *)fullName;

@end
```

And the Profile model implementation

```
#import "Profile.h"

@implementation Profile

@synthesize fullName = _fullName;

- (void)loadProfile:(NSString *)fullName
{
    _fullName = @"Full Name";
}

@end
```

As mentioned earlier, if the _fullName = @"Full Name" portion is used in the controller, this works no problem, and the text Full Name will display in the simulator.  If the Profile model is used, the application will build, no errors or warnings, yet no information is displayed.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something extremely simple, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Where do set the `profile` property on `DefaultProfileViewController`?  I don't see anything above that actually creates a `Profile` instance.

Comment: I was under the impression that property (nonatomic, strong) Profile *profile; in the header and synthesize profile = _profile; in the implementation took care of that.  I'm fairly new to objective-c, so this could very well be exactly what's wrong.  Where would I go about creating a Profile instance as you said?

Answer (score 1):

You code sample declares the property `profile` but nowhere do you actually set the profile.

Remember that declared properties in Objective-C 2.0 do **one thing** - which is to create the accessor methods for you "behind your back."  (In the "old days" we had to write accessor methods by hand.  Laborious; but you got very good at memory management!)

In your case, likely whatever class that instantiates `DefaultProfileViewController` needs to create a `Profile` object and the call `setProfile` on the new `DefaultProfileViewController` instance.

Something like this:

```
// create Profile object
Profile *aProfile = [[Profile alloc] init];
[aProfile loadProfile:@"John Doe"];
DefaultProfileViewController *vc = [[DefaultProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your nib name" bundle:nil];

// set the profile on your view controller
vc.profile = aProfile;

// add your view controller's view to the view hierarchy
// however you are doing that now...
```

Note, assumes ARC.